# Vue Js-Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

[Screenshot of the error I get in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxdS8.png)

[The method I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvtbG.png)

[In mounted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QKn7.png)

[MapState in the Computed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jup0u.png)

My code is working. But I don't understand this error. I couldn't find the solution. I ask for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you mutate state outside mutations and it's there:

```
this.systemstatus.splice(i, 1)
```

You could copy `systemstatus` by using spread operator, for example:

```
const systemStatusCopy = [...this.systemstatus]
```

and you won't get any errors, however state won't change either, but if you need it to change in a store, then add mutation and commit a mutation whenever you need.

Comment: Thank you Dawid. With your solution, the problem was fixed.